# Went over my credit limit by a bit.  I paid half of the balance today.  Any consequences?

Tags: canada, credit-card, fees, credit-limit

I saw that my card had went over the credit limit. I paid half of the balance off today. I also requested for additional credit. Will there be any penalty fees?

Answer (score 6):

If a fee shows up and you have been a good customer, give them a call, explain what you've explained here, and they may waive the fee.  Nothing to do now except wait and see.